# Running a T-SQL statement on a linked server

Tags: sql-server

Getting an syntax error "near 1". I also get an error in my `where` near the @ if I just remove the TOP1. Suggestions?

```
    DECLARE @MainHospital varchar(50) = 'Hospital1'
exec('

    select TOP 1 p.providerid, p.NAME, c.ClientType
    from providers p
    inner join hcfa_1450_main i on p.ProviderID=i.ProviderID
    left outer join ClientTypes c on i.ClientTypeID = c.ClientTypeID
    --where c.ClientType is not null
    where p.NAME = @MainHospital
    order by p.providerid

    ') at verticadb
```

Comment: Any reason you use `exec` instead of just executing the statement?

Comment: This means your statement didn't find any matching records, not that you need to use `exec`. Either there are no matching records among the joined tables, or there is no `provider` record with a `Name` field of `Hospital1` in the joined results

Comment: You are executing the query on *different servers*. If you want the query to execute at `verticadb` ensure you use the proper four-part table names, eg `verticadb.ThatOtherDB.dbo.hcfa_1450_main` etc

Comment: So is there not a way to include TOP1 and my WHERE paramenter in the exec structure? whether I need it or not?

Comment: There is, check the documentation. Just google for `T-SQL exec`. In this case, it's pointless because you are comparing different queries

Answer (score 1):

No need of `exec`

```
DECLARE @MainHospital varchar(50) = 'Hospital1'

select TOP 1 p.providerid, p.NAME, c.ClientType
from providers p
inner join hcfa_1450_main i on p.ProviderID=i.ProviderID
left outer join ClientTypes c on i.ClientTypeID = c.ClientTypeID
--where c.ClientType is not null
where p.NAME = @MainHospital
order by p.providerid
```

Comment: Retuns 0 results, I believe it needs to be in the current structure

Comment: @user3749447 no it doesn't. It it returns 0, it's because your statement doesn't actually match anything

Comment: I'll add 2 queries to my question that will show which 1 returns results and the other does not...

Comment: @user3749447 The first executes on a different server, the other locally. That's why they return different results

Comment: So is there not a way to include TOP1 and my WHERE paramenter in the exec structure? whether I need it or not?